# Audit tables with parameters

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, audit, audit-logging

I want to audit changes in several tables to a history table.
I read about triggers, the problem is that I want to receive a reason for the operation on the table as well as the backend user who did it not the DB user.

So I'll have like

Table 1

```
ID_TABLE_1
FIELD_A
FIELD_B
```

Table 2

```
ID_TABLE_2
FIELD_C
FIELD_D
```

Table HISTORY

```
TABLE_NAME
RECORD_ID
USER
REASON
OPERATION
```

Looking for the best aproach here, as I see I've two options:

I can create a trigger for the tables save TABLE_NAME , RECORD_ID and OPERATION
and then have a function to update USER and REASON ?
or

Create a function to do all that?

Answer (score 1):

Use predicates like INSERTING/UPDATING/DELETING in the trigger to determine which DML operation happens.

Try this:

```
create trigger trg_operation_type
  before insert or update
  on table_1
  for each row
begin
  case
    when inserting then
        --insert to history table
    when updating then
        --insert to history table
  end case;
end;
```

Comment: I've done that , the problem is that I've 2 parameters that aren't fields from the table and I want to save them.